# Photoshop CS5's use of Wintab driver

Tags: c, dll, wrapper, photoshop, wacom

Wacom's drivers have always been atrociously bad, so I'm currently working on a hack.

The main problem I'm having is with calibration on a tablet PC. And before you say anything: no, just no. I've tried literally dozens of drivers, and of the few that work, none allows calibration of Wintab input. You can calibrate MS Ink, but that does nothing for apps like Photoshop that don't support the Ink API.

Having researched the issue a bit, the way I plan to hack it is by writing a wrapper for wintab32.dll which adjusts data packets as they're sent to applications, enabling calibration and perhaps tweaks to pressure sensitivity and whatever else I feel Wacom should have supported all along.

The calibration function is trivial, as is wrapping wintab32.dll and getting at the data that needs calibrating. As far as I can tell there are about half a dozen functions that request packet data, and I've inserted code in each of them to modify said data.

It works, too, at least if I test it on some wintab sample projects.

Photoshop is different, though. I can confirm that it loads the wrapped DLL, opens a wintab context and uses the API to request packet data, which is then modified en route. But then Photoshop ignores the modifications and *somehow* gets at the original, uncalibrated data and uses that. I can find nothing in the Wintab documentation to suggest how this is even possible.

I'm pretty stumped. Any thoughts?

Could it be that Photoshop only requests packets from Wintab in order to clear the packet queue, and then does something else to actually read the state of the stylus? And if so, what could that be? Some secret, obscure way of polling the data using WTInfo? A hook into the data stream between Wintab and the underlying driver/serial port?

Comment: You might get a better response on this question if you focused on the actual problem in the beginning.

Comment: @ReturningTarzan: I am very interested in your wintab32.dll wrapper, I am doing something very similar, do you have any code you can share? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure, but maybe the input from Ink API is also being written on the canvas. I mean, you are writing using two inputs now, which is WinTab and Ink. Got it?
If only you could ignore the Ink input, then that will show the right result.
P/S: This is only a hunch.